# Get duration from multiple video files?

Tags: python, windows, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I want to extract video duration metadata from every video file in a specified directory and then view the total duration.

I need to extract the data from as much as thousands of videos overall. In Windows I can view the total duration for many files manually when selecting them in the explorer and going into details. For 1500 mp4 files it takes about 20 seconds to make the calculations and view the total time. It's  relatively much faster then what I'm currently getting when iterating with `FFprobe`.

[How fast I am currently getting the result with FFprobe.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cgf7.gif)

```
for filename in dirFiles:
   print(subprocess.check_output(['ffprobe', '-i', filename, '-show_entries','format=duration', '-sexagesimal' ,'-v', 'quiet', '-of', 'csv=%s' % ("p=0")]))
```

What is the faster way to do this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the how you were using `FFprobe` that you say was too slow—was it via `subprocess`?

Comment: It will be somewhat faster if you redirect the output to a log file and avoid the console printing as shown in [ffprobe Fastest way to read video packets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53267887/1109017), but instead of using `> output.log` you will want to use `>> output.log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with `mutagen` module as it handles files quite fast.

`mp4 = mutagen.mp4.MP4(filename)
duration+=mp4.info.length`

Answer (score 0):

There is no "best" way, just a best way for your use case. os.stat doesn't have it because video duration is not part of any posix file system, (files systems don't care about the contents of a file, Whats is the duration of a text file? what is the resolution of an executable?) If you don't like ffprobe, try mediainfo, or mp4box, or any other tool that can read media files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think the problem is that iterating through multiple files is not really optimised way as ffprobe is relaunching every time. I attached simple gif so you can get the idea of the speed. I got the same result when looping with ffprobe in cmd. I need the result almost instantly for every file.

Comment: Define `almost instantly`?

Comment: I need to process as much as thousands of video files overall. In Windows I can view the total duration for many files manually when selecting them in the explorer and pressing the properties>details. For 1500 mp4 files it takes about 20 seconds to calculate and display all details. Even though it's not instant it's still much faster then what I would get when iterating with ffprobe on all of them.